# Is there a pattern to track currently selected item in a container? Does state fits here?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, design-patterns

My original project is complex but I wrote a small demo which illustrates the problem and my question.

My model contains a list of objects. When I call its method `increment()`, it is applied to the current selected item. My question is how should I track the currently selected item?

My code below uses a pointer `currentItem` to track the current selected item. 
But my real project has do/undo functionality via command pattern so it needs to track. Additionally I have more states there to keep track of including current selected item and previous selected item.

Besides the code below, I have tried state design pattern but than I have to implement alot of the functions in the strategy that applies to the object and seems to complicate things. Is there a specific pattern for this? Does strategy suits here or is an overkill or perhaps simple plain pointer approach is fine? Please keep in mind my application needs to support do/undo functionality.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QList>


#define ITEM_COUNT  5

using namespace std;

class ObjectA {
public:
    ObjectA(string n, int p) {
        name = n;
        price = p;
    }

    string name;
    int price;

    void increment() {
        price++;
    }
};

class ContainerObject
{
public:
    QList<ObjectA*> items;

    ContainerObject() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++)
        {
            string name = ("name " + std::to_string((_ULonglong)i));
            ObjectA * item = new ObjectA(name, 0);
            items.append( item );
        }

        // assume at index 3 is current item
        setCurrentItem( items.at(2) );
    }

    ObjectA* currentItem;

    void setCurrentItem(ObjectA * obj) {
        currentItem = obj;
    }

    void increment(){
        currentItem->increment();

        if( currentItem->price >= 2)
            setCurrentItem( items.at( 4) );
    }

    void print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ITEM_COUNT; i++)
        {
            ObjectA * item = items.at( i );
            cout << item->name << "  " << item->price << " added" << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ContainerObject container;

    // initial values
    container.print();

    container.increment();
    container.print();

    container.increment();
    container.print();

    container.increment();
    container.print();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: This would be more suitable for Code Review.

Comment: Look up Cursor and/or Iterator patterns.

Answer (score 1):

First it seems that you have multiple opened questions :

1) How should you track the selected item?

There is no good answer it depends on your container's type. Here it seems that you have a list, then a **pointer approach** better fits compared to an **index approach** since the number of elements can vary (you could insert/append new items at different locations)

2) About the type of pattern to achieve this?

I haven't understood well why you tried to implement *State design pattern*, I assume because you read the assumption "it allows to adapt the behavior of an object when its internal state changes". I think that changing the selected item is not representative to an "internal state change" then it won't fit. It's usually used in state machine implementation.

For the specific purpose of undo/do there is anoter pattern which is called **memento design pattern**, it can recalls something important such as the previous selected item or so and allows you to restore the situation. I guess it could simplify your design when receiving a command :

- Recall the situation via memento (selected items...or more)
- Process the command (update selected items...)

if needed on undo command :

- Restore the situation

Comment: I think I agree pointer maybe the best way but was trying to be more sophisticated. I was state design pattern with iterator. I had `next()`, `changeState()` methods which sort of iterates through the states. I was calling the current selected item as a state and than i had iterators to each state. But I felt the code was getting complicated than being simpler.